# tryCatch in garchFit in R

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

When I run this program I get an error message after 160 'runs' (of 210):

```
    Error in solve.default(fit$hessian) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.24675e-16
    In addition: There were 35 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

When I get the error, the program stops. I have run the program with another set of data. Then it worked fine. How can I use tryCatch here so the program don't stops when an error occur?

```
minOrder <- c(0,0,1,0)
maxOrder <- c(5,5,2,2)
bestAIC <- 1e9
model <- list()
N1 <- ((0^minOrder[1]+maxOrder[1])*(0^minOrder[2]+maxOrder[2])*(0^minOrder[3]+maxOrder[3])*    (0^minOrder[4]+maxOrder[4]))
AIC <- numeric(N1)
MODEL <- mat.or.vec(N1,length(maxOrder))
i <- 1

for(p in minOrder[1]:maxOrder[1]){
for(q in minOrder[2]:maxOrder[2]){
    if(p==0 && q==0){q <- 1}
    for(m in minOrder[3]:maxOrder[3]){
        for(s in minOrder[4]:maxOrder[4]){      
            model <- garchFit(substitute(~arma(ar,ma)+garch(alpha,beta), list(ar=p,ma=q,alpha=m,beta=s)), data=logr, trace=F, cond.dist = c("norm"), include.mean=TRUE)
            AICmodel <- model@fit$ics[1]
            AIC[i] <- AICmodel
            MODEL[i,] <- c(p,q,m,s)
            i <- i+1
            if(AICmodel < bestAIC){
            bestAIC <- AICmodel
            bestFIT <- model
            bestMODEL <- c(p,q,m,s)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first identify which is the call that gives you the error. You can do this by calling `traceback()` after your program stopped. Then you enclose that call in a `try`. I guess that you receive the error when you call `garchFit`. If that is the case, you can:

```
    model <- try(garchFit(substitute(~arma(ar,ma)+garch(alpha,beta), list(ar=p,ma=q,alpha=m,beta=s)), data=logr, trace=F, cond.dist = c("norm"), include.mean=TRUE))
    if (class(model)=="try-error") next
```

`try` returns the result of the expression it enclose if successful or an object of class `try-error` with details of the error. If that's the case, you skip to the next iteration through `next`. You will receive the details of the error, but the program will keep going on. If you don't want any messagge desplayed, you call `try` with the `silent=TRUE` argument.